# Web audio cannot set position when the src uri is file stream

Tags: html, audio, stream

I want to play an mp3 audio with html audio element, but the src is not the location of the mp3 file, it is a output stream url like `http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/audio/stream` handled by java. Here is my problem.

I can receive the audio and play it, and `volume` and `playbackRate` perform well, but I cannot set its position using `audio.currentTime` attribute.

I can download the audio file when I access the stream url straight

Anyone knows what is going wrong? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, add these headers to the response header

`response.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
response.addHeader("Content-Length", length + "");
response.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + range + "-" + length + "/" + length);
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg;charset=UTF-8");`